# CUDA Visual Profiler v4.1, Possible to make Counter plot and to find detailed info about a kernel

Tags: cuda, profiler

In Visual Profiler v4.1

1. Is it possible to make Counter bar plot like in the old v3.2?
2. I have a kernel which have a number of device functions. Is it possible to see how long time each of this device functions take? To see which device function I could do some optimsations on.

Comment: What do you mean by Counter bar plot?  The answer to 2. is yes. This is the core function of the Visual Profiler: to profile.

Comment: harrism:
1. See link p. 53: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/Compute_Visual_Profiler_User_Guide.pdf


2. How? I can only see a timeline, where the total time for a kernel is showed. I want to se how each device function, in one kernel, perform without uncomment the various functions..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your 2.  You would have to split them into separate kernels.

Comment: @harrism: But what about q. 2? :-) Is it possible to plot that kind of a plot??

And are there other that can help me?